# XSLT 1.0 - Redundant Node After <xsl :if test ..> condition

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have an xslt file like below ;

```
<xsl:if test="/ItemList/Item/cx">
            <kml:Circle>

           </kml:Circle>

</xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="/ItemList/Item/Lon">
            <kml:Point>

          </kml:Point>

</xsl:if>
```

After executing this xslt on a xml file like the following , it  generates redundant tags like  `<kml:Point/>` and `<kml:Circle/>`. But I do not want this tag.

Sample XML File

```
<ItemList>
  <Item>
    <Name>1</Name>
    <Lon>66.406180329538</Lon>
    <Lat>35.7185924672465</Lat>

  </Item>
  <Item>
    <Name>2</Name>
    <cx>1</cx>
    <cy>2</cy>
    <rx>3</rx>
    <ry>4</ry>
  </Item>
</ItemList>
```

After executing xslt on this file sample output is like following ;

```
<kml:Placemark>
<kml:Circle cx="1" cy="2" r="3"/>
<kml:Point/>
</kml:Placemark>

<kml:Placemark>
<kml:Circle/>
<kml:Point>
<kml:coordinates>68.406180329538,35.7185924672465</kml:coordinates>
</kml:Point>
</kml:Placemark>
```

My question is , why there are nodes like `<kml:Point/>` and `<kml:Circle/>` after executing this xslt. I do not want this redundant nodes.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Can share the full XSLT file ?

Comment: just comment out those if statements if you don't need them.

Comment: @Al-MustafaAzhari https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55293788/xslt-1-0-redundant-tags-after-applying-transformation

Answer (score 0):

This XPath expression `/ItemList/Item/cx` is an [absolute location path](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#NT-AbsoluteLocationPath) and it doesn't depend on the context node that had matched the rule on your transformation. In short, it will always select the same nodes, thus it will always have the same boolean value.

Because your input document has both a `cx` and a `Lon` element (in different branch, but they both exist) your `xsl:if` instructions content will be processed.

Comment: This answer why you had that problem. In order to help you in your transformation code, we will need that you post a question with a complete but mininal input/stylesheet/desired output.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55293788/xslt-1-0-redundant-tags-after-applying-transformation